# Is my old router causing my internet problems

Tags: wireless-networking, router

My internet connection disconnects for 1-2 minutes every hour or so. When that happens I can't access the router's page 192.168.1.1 while I can access it normally even when the internet wire isn't connected to the router at all.

This problem is across all of our devices. There are usually 4 wireless devices connected to it. We got this router more than 6 years ago from our local ISP. (ZXHN H108N V2.5
)

I just want to know if the router is the culprit of my internet problems or not.

Sorry for the noob questions. And thank you for your answers

Comment: Where is your router? It could be that it is overheating.

Comment: It's out in the open in the living room. The sun isn't directly hitting it.

Comment: Is it your router?   It is sufficiently old and does not appear to be a mainline device that I would replace it. Does it belong to the ISP?  Ask them to service it.